# Solving interest Compounded Continuously with Calculus

Tags: calculus

The question is: Suppose you deposited $4000 at 6% interest compounded continuously. Find the average value of your account during the first 2 years.

$$
A = P \left( 1+\frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt} \,\, .
$$

I used this equation above and integrated it from 0 to 2, then divided by 2. I got 4494.4, 2247.2, and 4242.4, but none of them is right.

Comment: Why are you trying random numbers?

Comment: well the 4242 was pretty close @InterstellarProbe

Comment: Did you actually use any formula to try to solve the problem?

Comment: @saulspatz I edit my post and add a picture of the formula that I used. I can't quite figure out how to format the formula or equation yet, so I attached the picture instead.

Comment: @SakethMalyala So it seems like I used the wrong formula?

Comment: Here's a {mathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  The formula you linked is not the formula for continuous compounding.  Look at Saketh's answer to see the right formula.

Comment: your formula is correct! however, continuous compounding means n is basically infinite

Comment: when n is infinity, your expression (1+r/n)^nt is equal to e^rt

Comment: yearly measn n=1, monthly means n=12, daily means n=365, and continuous, means n is infinity

Answer (score 2):

Well, the value of your account at any time is given by $f(t) = 4000e^{0.06t}$, the formula of continuous compounding is $e^{rt}$.

Then, the average value of your integral would be $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2f(t)\,dt.$

This is equal to $\boxed{$4249.895}$